# Ubuntu 16.04 Hidpi support?

Tags: dell, 16.04, display-resolution, scaling

I just bought the new skylake Dell XPS 13 developer edition which came with 14.04, it had a bunch of issues slowing down the system, but the resolution was fine for my 3200x1800 screen.

I decided to fresh install 16.04, which fixed all the issues, however the resolution makes everything tiny. Is there support for this? Or some drivers I need to install? I changed the scale, but that isn't a great fix for much really.

Suggestions??